# Can't prevent label from extending the main window

Tags: python, tkinter

**Example**

(mimics the relevant parts of the layout in my real code)

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

# set up root
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(300, 50)
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)

# set up buttons that insert a short or a long string
textvar = tk.StringVar(value='foo')

def insert_short():
    textvar.set('foo')

def insert_long():
    textvar.set('foo'*30)

button_short = ttk.Button(frame, text='short', command=insert_short)
button_short.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_long = ttk.Button(frame, text='long', command=insert_long)
button_short.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_long.grid(row=0, column=1)

# set up label

# border for label to see its size
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure(
    'Bordered.TLabel', foreground='black', borderwidth=1, relief='solid')

# make label extend to the right
frame.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

# place label
label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=textvar, style='Bordered.TLabel')
label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.EW)

# place some other widget under label to mimic my real code
ttk.Button(frame, text='some other widget').grid(row=1, column=2)

# TRIED, NOT WORKING:
#root.resizable(False, False)
#frame.propagate(False)
#frame.grid_propagate(False)
#label.propagate(False)
#label.grid_propagate(False)

root.mainloop()
```

**Output**

[image]

[image]

**Question**

How do I prevent `label` from extending the main window?

(Bonus question, but not important: is there a way to make the label scrollable if it gets too long?)

**Attempts**

I tried the following commands:

```
root.resizable(False, False)
frame.propagate(False)
frame.grid_propagate(False)
label.propagate(False)
label.grid_propagate(False)
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen with the label? Do you just wat to chop off the extra characters? Or, do you want them to wrap, or do you want to be able to scroll them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a scrollable label using an `Entry` in a read-only state and by using scrolling it will prevent the widget from extending the main window.

Try replacing your label definition with the following code:

```
child_frm = ttk.Frame(frame)
label = ttk.Entry(child_frm, textvariable=textvar, style='Bordered.TLabel', state='readonly')
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(child_frm, orient='horizontal', command=label.xview)
label.config(xscrollcommand=scroll.set)
label.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.EW)
scroll.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.EW)
child_frm.grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Comment: Both answers are doing what I asked for. I flipped a coin which one to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default, the width of a Label is calculated based on its contents. You can override this behavior by specifying a value for `width` when creating the Label.

```
label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=textvar, style='Bordered.TLabel', width=1)
```

Much to my surprise, when I update your code with this, the label doesn't shrink to a size suitable for displaying exactly one character. It appears that the `sticky=tk.EW` argument of your `grid` call ensures that the label stays as wide as the widest element in the column.

[image]

Comment: Ironically, I don't want the label to shrink to the size of the string. I just want to prevent it from extending the width of the main window.

Comment: Both answers are doing what I asked for. I flipped a coin which one to accept. Thanks! (Do you have any clue why `grid_propagate` does not do the job?)